# How to add a different scheduler to a shell script in Linux?

Tags: linux, fifo

I am trying to use different schedulers to measure CPU usage among various programs. I am currently having trouble figuring out how to add a different scheduler to the script. I have tried using the chrt command, but I can not reliably get the pid for the script.

Comment: Show us what you have implemented so far, and the results it produces. It is not obvious that a filesystem chroot() operation will have much relevance to CPU scheduling techniques.

Comment: What shell are you using?

Comment: Show us what you have implemented. Code is precise; English sentences are ambiguous. I took chrt as a typo. I don't understand your remark that "I can not reliably get the pid for the script". If bash is in the shebang line, then surely `$$` gives the needed pid, no? You could, for example, echo it to a file in /tmp then access it later. https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0):

PIDs are fickle and racy (only the parent process of a PID can be sure it hasn't died and been recycled).

I'd use the first form (`chrt [options] prio command [arg]...`
) instead, relying on two scripts:

wrapper_script:

```
exec chrt --fifo 99 wrapee #wrapee must be in $PATH
```

wrapee:

```
echo "I'm a hi-priority hello world"
```